# How to suppress double-quote delimiters in output of Export[..., "tsv"]?

Tags: export

Toy example: I have a dataset `ds`, defined as

```
ds = Dataset[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "foo"|>,
              <|"a" -> 7, "b" -> "bar"|>,
              <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "baz"|>}];
```

If I export it with

```
Export["/tmp/ds.tsv", ds, "tsv"];
```

...the resulting file has the contents shown below:

```
a   b
1   "foo"
7   "bar"
3   "baz"
```

How can I suppress the double-quotes around each string in this output?

Comment: Normally this would do `"TextDelimiters" -> ""` but here it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am no expert on Datasets, but this works. Import it and export it again :)

```
ds = Dataset[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "foo"|>, <|"a" -> 7, 
     "b" -> "bar"|>, <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "baz"|>}];
Export["ds.tsv", ds, "tsv"];
Export["ds.tsv", Import["ds.tsv", "tsv", "Numeric" -> False], "tsv"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

ps. I know nothing about "tsv" file format. (but google says it is Excel?) So I do not know if this method has any side-effect on other `Datasets` that are not shown in this example.

Comment: "TSV" stands for Tab Separated Values.

Comment: @MarcoB Ok, thanks. In this case, I used "tsv" for everything. So it will keep the TAB in there.

Comment: Thanks!  Crazy, but it works!  BTW, I got better results when I added `"Numeric" -> False` to the `Import` expression.  You can see why if you replace the values for the `b` column with the strings `"000"`, `"001"`, `"002"`.

Comment: @kjo, thanks, if you say so, I believe you :) updated the answer so it is self contained.